# Don't allow the static menu go far from the fixed content while zooming OUT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, static

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<div id="content" style="height:500px; width:800px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#900;position:relative;">
    <div id="nonScrollableMenu" style="position:absolute; left:-80px;">
        <ul>
            <li>AAA</li>
            <li>BBB</li>
            <li>CCC</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

See how the ul behaves when you zoom in/out with the code above. Now I want the ul be static while scrolling. Only this needs to be added, with the same zoom in/out behavior. That is I dont want the ul be far from the  while zooming OUT. How it can be done?

P.S.
If you create static menu with CSS position:fixed property, the requirement in the title will not be satisfied. It will go far from the colored box when you zoom OUT.

Comment: Yes it is but that one was so much messed up that now nobody wants to answer my question. Sorry for posting again.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood your wish, maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
ul{position: fixed;}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't noticed your edit in the post :) If fixing position is not satisfying, then what is it that you want?

Comment: Oh, no, no no. If you do that, the when you zoom OUT, it will be very far from the colored rectangle. But I want to be always close to that and also fixed vertically. To be close as it is now when you zoom OUT.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to fix from the top like

```
<div id=nonScrollableMenu style="position:fixed;top:5%;">
```

and wrap two divs in in one wrapper container like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="nonScrollableMenu"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```